# How to disconnect your Nintendo Network ID from a 3DS you no longer have access to

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendo-network-id, nintendo-eshop

So, here the deal: I lost my old 3DS a few months ago and then for Christmas I got a used 3DS that had been factory reset. I went through the process of setting it up and then went to download the Badge Game from the EShop and couldn't because it wouldn't let me use my old NNID.

So my question is this: how do I disconnect my NNID from my old 3DS?